# How to cluster external geojson (using leaflet.ajax.js)?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, clustering, ajax

Understand the method of marker clustering but unable to find the right solution for external geojson. I have tried various cluster plugins but nothing seems to work. See example map [here](https://marinespatialviz.github.io/marinespatialviz/LitterMap.html).

`var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marinespatialviz/marinespatialviz/master/litter.geojson", {
         pointToLayer: function(feature, yx) {
           var icon = L.icon({
             iconUrl: feature.properties.gx_media_links,
             iconSize: [40, 40]});
             var marker = L.marker(yx, {icon: icon});
             marker.bindTooltip('<p>' + feature.properties.description + '</p>');
             return marker;
         }
       }).addTo(map);
var marker = L.markerClusterGroup();
marker.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
map.addLayer(marker);`

Comment: I looked at your code and haven't seen usage of clustering, can you please focus the question about specific lines?

Comment: See edited code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the geojson data for the clustering, you need to make sure that the data has loaded. The GeoJSON Ajax plugin has a listener for that - 'data: loaded':

`// Creating the markers 
var marker = L.markerClusterGroup();
geojsonLayer.on('data:loaded', function() { 
    // Add the cluster data after the geojson layer has loaded.
    marker.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
    map.addLayer(marker);
})`

So I just transfered the markers initiation into this listener's function.